# Python Resample - Pad does not fill NAN

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, pandas-resample

I am trying to fill in the `NaN's` after I upsample my timeseries with `resample's pad() function`.

I used the `resample('1min').asfreq` to upsample from hourly data to minute-interval data, then used `resample.('1min').pad()` it does not fill in the `NaN` values with the previous value as it should in this Pandas.Dataframe.resample [tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html).

**Run to create dataframe with datetime index**

```
url = "https://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/view_text_file.php?filename=42887h2016.txt.gz&dir=data/historical/stdmet/"
data_csv = urlopen(url)
df = pd.read_csv(data_csv, delim_whitespace=True, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
df.drop(['WDIR', 'WSPD', 'GST', 'WVHT', 'DPD', 'APD', 'MWD', 'PRES', 'VIS', 'TIDE', 'VIS', 'ATMP', 'WTMP'], 
        axis = 1, inplace = True)

#Data Preparation
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
df = df.iloc[1:]
df = df.rename(columns={'#YY': 'YY'})

#Create datetime variable
df['Date'] = df[df.columns[0:3]].apply(lambda x: '/'.join(x.dropna().astype(int).astype(str)),axis=1)
df['Time'] = df[df.columns[3:5]].apply(lambda x: ':'.join(x.dropna().astype(int).astype(str)),axis=1)
df['Date.Time'] = df['Date'] + ':' + df['Time']
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = '%Y/%m/%d')
df['Date.Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date.Time'], format='%Y/%m/%d:%H:%M', utc=True)

#Remaining data prep for the dataframe and create index w/ time date
df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
df = df[(df['MM'] == 2.0) | (df['MM'] == 3.0)]
df = df.replace(999, np.nan)
df = df.set_index('Date.Time')
df.drop(['hh', 'mm', 'Time', 'Date'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

**The result is the dataframe we want:**

```
                             YY  MM  DD  DEWP
Date.Time                                    
2016-12-01 00:00:00+00:00  2016  12   1  11.3
2016-12-01 01:00:00+00:00  2016  12   1   9.0
2016-12-01 02:00:00+00:00  2016  12   1  11.0
2016-12-01 03:00:00+00:00  2016  12   1  10.8
2016-12-01 04:00:00+00:00  2016  12   1   6.5
```

**Now resample up to 1 min from an hour**

```
df = df.resample('1min').asfreq()
df.head()
```

**Results:**

```
                               YY    MM   DD  DEWP
Date.Time                                         
2016-12-01 00:00:00+00:00  2016.0  12.0  1.0  11.3
2016-12-01 00:01:00+00:00     NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN
2016-12-01 00:02:00+00:00     NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN
2016-12-01 00:03:00+00:00     NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN
2016-12-01 00:04:00+00:00     NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN
```

**Fill in NaN values with Pad command**

```
df = df.resample('1min').pad()
df.head()
```

**Results:**

```
                               YY    MM   DD  DEWP
Date.Time                                         
2016-12-01 00:00:00+00:00  2016.0  12.0  1.0  11.3
2016-12-01 00:01:00+00:00     NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN
2016-12-01 00:02:00+00:00     NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN
2016-12-01 00:03:00+00:00     NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN
2016-12-01 00:04:00+00:00     NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN
```

**Variable `DEWP` is supposed to look like this**

```
                               YY    MM   DD  DEWP
Date.Time                                         
2016-12-01 00:00:00+00:00  2016.0  12.0  1.0  11.3
2016-12-01 00:01:00+00:00  2016.0  12.0  1.0  11.3
2016-12-01 00:02:00+00:00  2016.0  12.0  1.0  11.3
2016-12-01 00:03:00+00:00  2016.0  12.0  1.0  11.3
2016-12-01 00:04:00+00:00  2016.0  12.0  1.0  11.3
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `df.resample('1min').fillna("pad")` worked. Documentation can be found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html).